# Cocos2d: which information can I extract from a ccTouchesEnded event?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, touch, multi-touch

Stupid question but for me very useful to clarify.

I am developing a game where I would like to recognize a series of two consecutive swipes (horizontal and vertical) to trigger a special shoot.

Here it comes the problem. When I deal with ccTouchesEnded, ccTouchesMoved ccTouchesBegan methods there are some concurrency issues in case of multitouch events.

The issues is that if I am evaluating a series of touches (touchBegan at position(0,0), touchMoved at pos(1,0), touchMoved at pos(2,0), touchEnded at pos(3,0)) and the user starats a new touch series (say at position (10,40)) then will be difficult for me to distinguish between the two series.

Any suggestions?

Is the NSSet of touches in the functions provided by Cocos2d useful?

Eg:

```
-(void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
-(void) ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

How can I distinguish between the various touches? I mean, when

```
-(void) ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store incoming touches and then check if they are in `touches` parameter of  `ccTouchesMoved`/`ccTouchesEnded`/`ccTouchesCancelled`, and handle them accordingly. Don't forget to remove stored touches when they `ccTouchesEnded`/`ccTouchesCancelled`.

Comment: How do I distinguish between two parallel touch events?

Comment: if (touch == mySomehowStoredEarlierTouch)